# How to switch 2nd and 4th digit(before comma) in a double? C programming

Tags: c

So lets say the input is 4**5**3**9**2.56, the output has to be 4**9**3**5**2.56.
How can i program this in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dotPos(char arr[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (arr[++i] != '.');
    return i;
}

int main() {
    double d = 45392.56;

    int MAX = 100;
    char arr[MAX];
    sprintf(arr, "%f", d);

    if (dotPos(arr) > 3) {
        char aux = arr[1];
        arr[1] = arr[3];
        arr[3] = aux;
    }

    d = atof(arr);
    printf("%.2f\n", d);
}
```

Output:

```
49352.56
```

Comment: `char arr[sizeof(d)];` That might be just a little bit too small. (and `main()` should return int)

Comment: why using `%2.2f`? You don't need any justification there. Only `%.2f` is needed.

Comment: Yeah, Parnab. My mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, wildplasser. The method return was changed to int.

Comment: Tnx for your help @MarcelJacquesMachado

Comment: So if the input is 73, how can i get the output 7003? @MarcelJacquesMachado

Comment: What `sizeof(d)` returns is not the size a "string" needs to provide to hold `d`'s text representation.

Comment: OK, @alk and wildplasser. Let's replace sizeof(d) by a constant MAX.

Comment: Yeah, @wildplasser. I have tested. =)

Comment: @rich-mirin, I have changed the code to attend the other requisite: switch digits before comma only.

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado ... and the result was `135492.56` ?

Comment: Exactly, @wildplasser.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the number to a character array. Look at the `sprintf` function.
2. Swap the positions of the characters.
3. Convert the character array to double. Look at the `atof` function.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding conversion to string and back, take the integral part of the number, find the two values in position 1 and 3 (in decimal notation), and compute the value to add or substract to/from the original double.
this is `(a-b) *pow(10,hipos) - (a-b) * pow(10,lopos)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

long finddiff(unsigned long val, unsigned lpos, unsigned rpos);

int main(void) {
    double d = 45392.56;
    unsigned long u;
    long dif;

    u = d;
    dif = finddiff(u,3,1);

    d += dif;

    printf("%.2f\n", d);
    return 0;
}

long finddiff(unsigned long val, unsigned lpos, unsigned rpos)
{
long res;
unsigned pos, ll, rr;

if (lpos < rpos) return finddiff(val, rpos,lpos);

for (pos=0; pos < rpos; pos++) { val /= 10; }
rr = val %10;
for (; pos < lpos; pos++) {  val /= 10; }
ll = val %10;

// fprintf(stderr, "%u,%u\n", ll,rr);

res = rr-ll;
for (; pos > rpos; pos--) { res *= 10; }
res -= rr-ll;
for (; pos > 0; pos--) { res *= 10; }

// fprintf(stderr, "%u,%u,%ld\n", ll,rr, res);

if (ll > rr) res = -res;
else if (rr > ll) {;}
else res = 0;
return res;
}
```

BTW: this will fail miserably for values whose integer part is larger than the maximum log int, eg `6.3E23` .
For negative numbers some additional logic should be added.