# Switching the 2nd and 4th digit from right(rightmost) in a double

Tags: c

My question is pretty much the same as the question asked here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677935/how-to-switch-2nd-and-4th-digitbefore-comma-in-a-double-c-programming)

The difference is that I want to switch the 2nd and 4th digit from the right, instead of the left like in the other question. So rightmost number in my case is 1. 
Example: 28**3**9**2**6.67 becomes 28**2**9**3**6.67. 
How do I code this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {


    double number;

    printf("Give a number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &number);

    //printf("%.4f", number);

    char arr[sizeof(number)];
    snprintf(arr, sizeof(number) + 1, "%f", number);

    char ex = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[3];
    arr[3] = ex;

    number = atof(arr);
    printf("%.4f\n", number);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch 2nd and 4th digit(before comma) in a double? C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677935/how-to-switch-2nd-and-4th-digitbefore-comma-in-a-double-c-programming)

Comment: @TheoPnv How about you read what I wrote?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Added my code:)

Comment: @Sullivan It's normal to tag questions as duplicates, even if you mentioned it. Try not to have harsh words for people doing the moderation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do the exact same thing as in the link you've given:

```
int main() {
    double A = 282936.67;

    char str[50];
    sprintf(str, "%f", A);

    int dot = -1, i = 0;
    //Finds the dot position
    while (i != 50) {
        if (str[i] == '.') {
            dot = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (dot >= 4) {
        char tmp = str[dot - 2];//Search from the dot position
        str[dot - 2] = str[dot - 4];
        str[dot - 4] = tmp;
    }
    //Convert your string to a float
    A = atof(str);
    printf("%.2f", A);

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what happens exactly in the if statement?

Comment: Which one ? The firs one checks if it finds the dot somewhere, the second one checks if the dot is located far enough to get the `dot -4` character, otherwise you would get an exception when checking `str[dot - 4]`

Comment: Oh I see and why does int dot have the value -1?

Comment: `dot`can be initialized with any value under 4 without changing anything in the *actual* program, i just put `-1` to clearly show that if there is no dot in the array, its result won't point to a wrong value